# phpmyadmin export selected data from SQL to excel

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, phpmyadmin

I have a problem where I need to just export selected data from my phpmyadmin, i'm using XAMPP.

I have a table named "`Tbl_Records`" and I only need to get all the data of year 2014 or just a specific year in that table.

I tried

```xml
Select * From Tbl_Records Where Year = 2014
```

in Phpmyadmin to get only the specific year and then exported the data but it still exported everything.

Comment: What version of phpmyadmin are you using?  After you run the query, make sure to use the Export link below the table, not the Export Tab at the top of the page.

Comment: You solved my question dude, how can i give you a + point or something for your answer? Thanks very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `Export` link located under the data from the query and not the *Export* tab at the top, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: when I click that option on a query with subqueries it forgets the query and goes to the whole table.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - it does appear that way, but go ahead and follow through to completion. The export will only contain the data you selected, despite appearances.